# Android open pdf file from Url and diaplay in web view?

Tags: android, pdf

I know this question has been asked so many time , but i didn't get any proper and satisfactory solution. I want to show the Pdf file in web view , which is coming from the url ,when i click on the URL , my pdf downloads. Currently i am usinghtml following code for showing pdf file in web view , but it is opening the html file. I am getting stuck in this since 4 hours.Kindly suggest me where i am doing wrong.

Thanks in advance.

```
        mWebview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        WebSettings settings = mWebview.getSettings();
        settings.setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8");
        mWebview.loadData(response, "application/pdf; charset=utf-8",null);
```

i have following response coming in following format :-

```
**%PDF-1.4%���5 0 obj<</E 74937/H [ 1453 173 ]/L 75330/Linearized 1/N 1/O 8/T 75180>>**
```

Comment: `response` is a String?

Comment: no its a byte response

Comment: try using direct URL. no need to download whole file.

Comment: you definitely need to convert the bytes into pdf file first.. the load it on webview.. webview only receive in form of html or url

Answer (score 0):

> I want to show the Pdf file in web view

`WebView` does not have a PDF renderer.

> Kindly suggest me where i am doing wrong.

You are attempting to load a PDF directly into a `WebView`. Use [something else to render the PDF](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/01/04/options-viewing-pdfs.html).

Comment: Thanks for your answer , but currently i am getting url in the form of bytes , so how should i use that to show in web view , i am getting stucked form morning ...:(

Comment: @RajshreeTiwari: Write the bytes to a file. Then, [use something else to render the PDF file](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/01/04/options-viewing-pdfs.html). It's possible that the Pdfium stuff supports an `InputStream` (in your case, a `ByteArrayInputStream`), but I am not aware that it does.

Answer (score 0):

For show pdf in webview use Direct url:

```
 https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url="PDF_FILE_URL"
```

Now load above url in webview.

```
mWebview.loadUrl("https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url="PDF_FILE_URL"");
```

Comment: Thanks divyesh , i tried this, but it is not working because my url is not string it is in bytes form

Comment: from where you get pdf file?

Comment: from server this file is coming

Comment: then use that server url to show pdf. post your url that is coming from server

Comment: try this url:    https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=devcal.hitechpmr.com/PDF/GetCustomerInvoicePdf?invoiceID=INV04122017001