# How to display pdf view or document view in android using firebase uri without external libraries

Tags: android, pdf, firebase, webview, firebase-storage

- I won't display firebase storage pdf file in app

  ```
      <WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" style="@style/layout_match_wrap" android:id="@+id/webVi"/>
  ```

```
  reView.setVisibility(WebView.VISIBLE);
  reView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
  reView.setWebViewClient(new AppWebView());
  reView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
  reView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
  reView.loadUrl(url);
```

above code i am using for display pdf but still not open.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43589118/115145

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
String url = "http://www.axmag.com/download/pdfurl-guide.pdf";
 webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
 webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
 webView.loadUrl("http://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?embedded=true&url=" + url);
```

Comment: That's already answered in the duplicate post that's flagged, by the way.

Comment: thanks for reply but i am using firebase url like: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/o/QoeRpRpZYOXXjvjL0hjt8ghrkl53%2FResume%2Fpavithra.resume.docx?alt=media&token=acf2db1e-fa0e-46d0-a8bc-3618b8c4a505

Comment: Firebase Storage download URLs are just URLs. They don't require any special treatment in this scenario.

Comment: thanks for reply i am using url but not able to view pdf content in android app, why it is like that, but same link i try to past it in chrome browser it will directly download the file ,but firefox browser it will ask pop-up like save,download.